# Overloading in local methods and lambda

Tags: c#, lambda, c#-7.0

```cs
static void Main() {
  void TestLocal() => TestLocal("arg");
  TestLocal("arg");
}
static void TestLocal(string argument) {
}
```

In this example, local function has the same name as another method, which I want to overload. But this method is invisible from inside of this function, and even from inside of `Main()`. The same is for lambdas:

```cs
static void Main() {
  Action TestLambda = () => TestLambda("arg");
}
static void TestLambda(string argument) {
}
```

I understand, why lambda hides outer method - because it is a local variable, and local variables always work this way. But I don't see any reason for local functions hide and not overload outer methods - it could be very useful for reducing amout of arguments in local scope, doing some kind of carrying.

Why local functions hide methods?

**EDIT:**

I can imagine an example where it gets complicated

```cs
void Bar(short arg) {
  Console.WriteLine("short");
}
void Bar(byte arg) {
  Console.WriteLine("byte");
}
void Test() {
  void Bar(int arg) {
    Console.WriteLine("int");
  }
  Bar(0);
}
```

It was already complicated enough with argument type resolution. If they added overloading to local methods, it would be one more stupid task for job interviews and one more huge task for compiler makers. And there are also `virtual` and `new` methods...

Comment: true but you still can get access to the hidden method, in this case by referring the class because it's static `Program.TestLocal("arg")`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Why local functions hide methods?

Basically it's introducing the method name into the *declaration space* inside the method. Within that declaration space, the name *only* refers to the local method... just as it does for a local variable. I think that's reasonably consistent with the way that names introduced into methods have always worked.

I'd personally advise against trying to do this anyway, as it'll cause confusion, but if you really need to refer to the class method, just make it explicit:

```
ClassName.TestLocal("arg");
```

What I *do* think could be fixed is that local methods can't be overloaded between themselves. You can't write:

```
void Foo()
{
    void Method(int x) {}
    void Method(string y) {}
}
```

This is for a related reason - a method's declaration space can't include the same name twice, whereas a class's declaration space *can* do so, in terms of method overloading. Maybe the rules will be loosened around this...

Comment: Right, calling it with explicit class name (or `this`) is certainly a solution. Still, it feels too restricted. I don't see why to apply the same exactly visibility rules to functions.  What kind of troubles it helps to avoid?

Comment: @AlexButenko: It's more that it makes local methods a smaller change to the language: it doesn't mean extra rules for local methods, and probably simplifies overload resolution too.

Comment: Hmm. I am thinking what kind of corner case can be with overloading.