# Detecting an overload outside of a locally defined function?

Tags: c#

I am wondering why i can't detect my overload of a function when i declare one of them inside another function... example given below:

```
    private int Get(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        return x+y+z;
    }
    private int Get(int size)
    {
        int Get(int x, int y)
        {
            return x+y;
        }
        int a = Get(size,size) + Get(1, 2, 3);

        return a;
    }
```

I get this error:
`No overload for method 'Get' takes 3 arguments`

How come i can't access that method if i define a different overload inside another?

This isn't code i'd ever use its ugly and messy in my opinion, but i'm curious why i lose access once a define an overload locally.

Comment: The short answer - because it doesn't let you. Overloads aren't supported in local functions (so, for example, you can't have two different `Get` local functions inside of a function as well).

Comment: Ah i see. Is there a reason they don't allow local overloads? Was it a technical reason or just because its unlikely any one would need it so it prevents messy design ?

Comment: Do note that in this situation, you can still refer to `Get(int,int,int)` as `this.Get`. `Get` in this scope refers only to the local function `Get(int,int)`. Why is still pretty much what mjwills said - that's how the language was defined.

Comment: Other functions not found by just `Get` are the calling function itself - so if you wanted to make this recursive then you would still need to use `this.Get`.
The most sensible option is probably just not naming local functions the same thing as other functions. They have a very limited scope and it's probably not sensible for them to share a name with member functions of the same class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48579516/overloading-in-local-methods-and-lambda may be worth a read.

Comment: @mjwills - good find, this actually looks like a duplicate on reading that question. And that question already has a good answer.